# Boundary of a 2-singular simplex

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let a topological space $X$ and a 2-singular simplex $\sigma:\Delta_2\rightarrow X$.

I call the vertex $A=\sigma(U_0)$, $B=\sigma(U_1)$ and $C=\sigma(U_2)$ where $U_i$ is vertex of $\Delta_2$ with coordinates all zero and 1 in position $i$ (point of $\Delta_2$ are expressed in barycentric coordinates).

The boundary of $\sigma$ is $\partial_2\sigma=\sigma_0-\sigma_1+\sigma_2$ where $\sigma_i=\sigma\circ F_i^2$ ($F_i^2$ is the standard face operator).

$\Delta_1$ coincide with $I=[0,1]$ and i considered $\sigma_i$ as path of $X$.

In particular $\sigma_0$ go from B to C; $\sigma_1$ from A to C and $\sigma_2$ from A to B.

I call: the path $\sigma_2*\sigma_0$ is homotopic to $\sigma_1$ ? I can't build a path homotopy.

(* is the operation of giuntion between path)

Answer (score 1):

In $\Delta_2$ itself, for each $i=0,1,2$ we may consider $F^2_i : \Delta_1 \to \Delta_2$ to be a path in $\Delta_2$.

Since $F^2_2 * F^2_0$ and $F^2_1$ are paths in $\Delta_2$ with the same initial endpoint $U_0$ and and the same terminal endpoint $U_2$, and since the topological space $\Delta_2$ is contractible, it follows that there is a homotopy $h : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to \Delta_2$ from the path $F^2_2 * F^2_0$ to the path $F^2_1$.

The composed function $H = \sigma \circ h : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to X$ is therefore a homotopy from $\sigma_2 * \sigma_0$ to $\sigma_1$.